# Google Cloud Engine upgrade machine type issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have upgrade the Google cloud machine type from n1-standard-2 2(virtual cpus) to n1-standard-4 4(virtual cpus), Now i can't access the website. In SSH it shows error "we are unable to connect to the VM Port 22".

I have followed this video for upgrading https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-drO_2P6Xnc

Comment: Do you have access to Google cloud web portal ?. If so, login and check your instance is up and running.

Comment: Yes, its running.

Comment: Ok, then, Launch it from the Web UI => Google Cloud Platform -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances -> Instance -> Connect (SSH)->Open in browser Window. Further, check the External IP and make sure the instance is reachable from the external network.

Answer (score 0):

***[Could anyone change my answer to a comment?]***

I was not able to reproduce your issue. At this point, I would recommend you to start troubleshooting the SSH issue by following [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors)

Check serial console (look for errors) of your instance by running the following command:
$ gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output INSTANCE